# How to enable particular Reminder in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have list of Reminders bounded in the Listbox control.Toggle Switch is also bounded against a reminder.

So when user switch "ON" the reminder from Toggle switch i wanted to Enable that particular remider.

I see that Reminders in Windows Phone 7 has IsEnabled and IsScheduled Property but it does not allow to set the value to that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminders on the phone are in the user control once submitted, the app no longer has access to them.
When you use the Calendar tasks you don't actually have write access to the calendar you just prompt the user if they want to save that reminder.

I'm guessing you have already gone through this tutorial for creating reminders and alerts.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx

In Windows Phone 8 this same is true, to most phone services we only have read and prompt to create.